# Signaling a long running Huey task to stop

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-rest-framework, python-huey

I'm using Huey to perform some processing operations on objects I have in my Django application.

```py
@db_task()
def process_album(album: Album) -> None:
    images = album.objects.find_non_processed_images()

    for image in images:
        if album.should_pause():
            return

        process_image(album, image)
```

This is a simplified example of the situation I wish to solve. I have an `Album` model that stores a various number of `Images` that are required to be processed. The processing operation is defined in a different function that s wrapped with `@task` decorator so it'll be able to run concurrently (when the number of workers > 1).

The question is how to implement `album.should_pause()` in *the right way*. Current implementation looks like this:

```py
def should_pause(self):
    self.refresh_from_db()
    return self.processing_state != AlbumProcessingState.RUNNING
```

Therefore, on each iteration, the database is queried to update the model, to make sure that `state` field didn't change to something other than `AlbumProcessingState.RUNNING`, which would indicate that the album processing tasks should break.

Although it works, it feels wrong since I have to update the model from the database on each iteration, but these feelings might be false. What do you think?